# Javascript returning a specific integer in a string while removing the rest

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I have a url query that for example looks like this after a `decodeURIComponent` 
`["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[1500 TO 1999.99]"]` the results I want is "1999.99".

What I have right now is

```
const query = ["pcs_availability:Online", "price:[1500 TO 1999.99]"]
const price = query.find((item) => item.match("price")).split(/::|:/)[1].split(" ")[2].replace("]", "");
```

Which gives me back 1999.99 which is what I want but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this instead. Unfortunately I am not able to change the way the query is structured so I have to work with that.

Comment: Is the query array always in the same format?

Comment: @kevkev yeah it's mostly in the same format but for some reason sometimes it'll be separated by 2 `::` not sure why so for example next to the price
`["pcs_availability:Online", "Brand:", "price::[150 TO 249.99]"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the easier approach is to use a regular expression with a capture group.

```
const pattern = /^price:{1,2}\[.*? TO (.*?)]$/;
const price = query
  .map(q => {
    const match = pattern.exec(q);
    return (match && match[1]) || null;
  })
  .find(maybePrice => maybePrice !== null);
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that's a much better solution! Totally forgot an edge case. Sometimes there can be more than 1 price range that comes back is there a good way to make it so that it only would run if it's just 1 price range? For example in this case it should return null.
`["pcs_availability:Online", "Brand:", "price:[150 TO 249.99]:[250 TO 499.99]"]`

Comment: Updated. Before I was using greedy `*`; changed to non-greedy, so now it should just match if there's one. Also added double-colon support.

Comment: Hey thanks again for all the help! I don't mean to keep bothering you but I just realized that I actually need it returned as an array with all the prices. For example with multiple price ranges it should look like this `[249.99, 499.99]`. Thanks again!

Comment: Try expanding on the example I gave. Add `()`'s around the other number you need to capture, and then your array returned from `pattern.exec` will have that other item.